# Why has my image lost its transparency?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uibutton, xib

I'm creating a xib file in which there is a black marbled background displayed using a UIImageView and several UIButtons placed over it with images within them. The images are transparent with the exception of a dotted white line skirting their perimeter. I am using pngs for my images and I have tried setting them as both the image and background image. How can I restore the alpha channel within these images and place them within a UIButton?

How the image should look with transparency against a black marbled background.

[image: How the image should look against a marbled black background]

How the image looks at present.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to set your button type to `UIButtonTypeCustom`?

Comment: try with button type-Custom in xib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to set the `UIButton` type to `UIButtonTypeCustom` and not Rounded Rect

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's literally all that was needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add quartzCore framework in your framework folder, then import the header:

```
#import < QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h >
```

and set the image `maskToBounds` yes and set in corner if you want.

```
[yuorImageView.layer setMaskToBounds:YES];
```